# Multi-touch for my rotation KineticJs

Tags: javascript, html, kineticjs, puzzle

i am currenly using kineticJs v4.5.3 , i am doing jig-saw puzzle and my puzzle can be rotate with "click" event , but now i want to change to multi-touch which allows me to use 2 finger or hands to rotate the jig-saw pieces, anyone have any idea of that? Thanks :)

```
piecesArray[i][j].shape.on("mousedown", function () {
    this.moveToTop();
    this.rotateDeg(90)
    layer.draw();
});
```

My JsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/e70n2693/7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use HammerJS with KineticJS v5.1.0:

```
Hammer(rect).on('rotate', callback);
```

https://github.com/lavrton/KineticJS-HammerJS-test

http://jsfiddle.net/lavrton/w4HgN/

Comment: sorry, but i cant use kineticJs v5.1.0 , i have an error, do you know why? http://jsfiddle.net/e70n2693/8/

Comment: fillStroke -> fillStrokeShape

Comment: And `drawFunc` have context as argument.

Comment: sorry, can i ask you why is my rotation so weird with this code? `rotation : Math.PI * 0.5 * Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)` thanks :) how do i make it rotation 90degree randomly?

Comment: `var x = Math.random();  var rotation = Math.PI * 0.5 * Math.floor((x - 0.5)/ Math.abs(x - 0.5))`

Comment: thanks :) `Hammer(rect).on('rotate', callback);` is just an example or i can add it in on my code?